# Update table using variables

Tags: php

I want to update a table using a array but I can't get it to work. It inserts the date in the table but the update query doesn't work.

```
<?php
session_start();
$dateinsert = $_SESSION['aanwezigheidsdatum'];
$nameninsertarr = $_SESSION['namen'];
for ($i =2 ; $i<$_SESSION['totaalpersoneel'];$i++){
  $test = $_GET["ureninsert".$i];
  if ($test == ""){$test = X;}
  $ureninsertarray[$i-2] = $nameninsertarr[$i-2]." = '".$test."'";
}
$ureninsertarr = implode(' , ',$ureninsertarray);
echo $ureninsertarr;

include("connectdb.php");
$query = "INSERT INTO Aanwezigheidslijst (dag) VALUES ('$dateinsert')";
mysql_query($query);
$query = "UPDATE 'Aanwezigheidslijst' SET $ureninsertarr WHERE dag = '$dateinsert'";
echo "<br>".$query;
$putquery = mysql_query($query);
if (!$putquery) echo "error";
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated.Use `mysqli_query`........

Comment: Or `PDO` but definitely no `mysql`

Comment: what `$dateinsert` contains ?

Comment: Maybe change the '' around your table name, to backticks ``? MySQL, probably sees that as a string. Or removed them completely as you're not consistent from your INSERT to your UPDATE ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats  because u have written update syntax wrong.u have to specify column name in 'set'.fix this issue and ur update query will work.

```
$query = "UPDATE Aanwezigheidslijst
SET column_name=$ureninsertarr
WHERE dag = $dateinsert";
```

update syntax:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
[WHERE where_condition]
[ORDER BY ...]
[LIMIT row_count]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "UPDATE 'Aanwezigheidslijst' SET $ureninsertarr WHERE dag = '$dateinsert'";
```

should be changed in

```
 $query = "UPDATE `Aanwezigheidslijst` SET $ureninsertarr WHERE dag = '$dateinsert'";
```

But should use another way to talk with your database. (PDO?)

In PDO it would look like

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `Aanwezigheidslijst` SET $ureninsertarr WHERE `dag` = ?");
$dbh->execute(array($dateinsert));
```

You should also take care or params used in $ureninsertarr. Getting them directly from $_GET means that you don't really know what is beeing inserted into you DB. (!SQL Injection!)

[PDO Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

EDIT: as posted before, $ureninsertarr needs to be a string that also cointains the columns nam. Not only the values...